# The Use of the Past or Present Progressive Tenses in Zero Conditionals

Tags: conditionals

Is it correct to use the past progressive tense in both clauses in a conditional sentence?

And can I use the past progressive and past simple in a conditional sentence?

Comment: You should include some examples to illustrate what you want clarified.

Comment: First, progressive is an aspect not a tense. Second, English does not have numbered conditionals. That's merely a crutch that ESL teachers make foreign students use. Therefore you should be on the Learner's site.